# Scala regex match failing with scala.MatchError for \w and \d (word or digit) match

Tags: regex, scala

I was trying some basic regex pattern matching. Although my syntax seems to be correct, it's failing when I use `\w` or `\d` for word and digit matching.

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object ex {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val pattern =  new Regex("(\\w)\\s(\\d)");
    val pattern(words,num) = "asas1 11"
    print(words+" "+num)
  }
}
```

This is error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: asas1 11 (of class java.lang.String)
    at com.cccu.semantic.ex$.main(ex.scala:8)
    at com.cccu.semantic.ex.main(ex.scala)
```

Note: I am using the Scala IDE build of the Eclipse SDK, Build ID 4.4.1 with Scala 2.11.8 on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` and `\d` will match single character, you need to add there `+` modifier. It is throwing an exception because it can't match input against your regular expression.

```
scala> val pattern =  new Regex("(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)");    val pattern(words,num) = "asas1 11"
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w+)\s(\d+)
words: String = asas1
num: String = 11
```

Comment: `\w\s\d` would actually match `1 1` in the test string the OP provided.

Comment: @Tomalak you are wrong, it is throwing an exception as you can see. According to documentation: "Note, however, that when Regex is used as an extractor in a pattern match, it only succeeds if the whole text can be matched. " http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/util/matching/Regex.html

Comment: Ah, I see. I was looking at the regex on its own.